# Import "bs4" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup

when I write `bs4` on vs code it said

```
    Import bs4 could not be resolved from source
```

and it has a yellow underline

and I tried to write in the terminal `install beautifulsoup4` many times but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip install beautifulsoup4` to install the package with `pip`.

For more information about `python` packages read [Installing python packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/) and [Managing packages with `pip`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#managing-packages-with-pip)

Answer (score 1):

When using `vscode`, and creating a virtual environment, you have to set the interpreter correctly in `vscode`.

On mac you can press `⌘Cmd + Shift + P`, `Ctrl + Shift + P` on windows - and then `Python: Select interpreter`. Browse to and select the correct python virtual environment.